# Set global variables in c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

I tried to set a global variable with a livetime during one pagerequest.

In classic als i used this like this:

---

```
dim VariableName
VariableName = "test";

sub testsub()
    VariableName += VariableName + "new"
    response.write VariableName
end sub

response.write VariableName '-> test
testsub() '-> testnew
```

---

Now in asp.net i tryed to set the variable in my class like this:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string GlobalVar = "test";

    public static string MyMethod()
    {
        GlobalVar += GlobalVar + "new";

        return GlobalVar;
    }
}
```

But now, the problem is, that this variable are like a application variable with a lifetime over all pagerequest.

Where can i define a varible with a lifetime during one request and availiable in all methods and other classes?

Comment: This has bad design written all over it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["ThisVariableHasRequestScope"] = "SomethingFancy";
```

**Edit:**

A simple example

AClass.cs :

```
public class AClass {
    public void Something() {
        // Set the value
        HttpContext.Current.Items["Test"] = "xxx";
    }
}
```

BClass.cs

```
public class BClass{
    public void SomethingElse() {
        // Get the value
        var test = HttpContext.Current.Items["Test"] as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to set this variable in MyClass and not in MyMethod(). Because I have to use this global variable in other files and classes, too. How I have to set this variable?

Answer (score 2):

Try using ASP.NET **Session** and see if it fits yours needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also to use [`Page.Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context.aspx) property as it will be available during all page lifecycle.